# Find the current at the resistor

Tags: resistors, current-source, ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws, current-divider

I've tried to divide current at 8A and then make a Kirchhoff voltage law between the resistor and dependent current source but I still can't solve it.

[image]

Comment: you have to show some effort... present what have you done so far

Comment: Not only effort in solving the problem, but in presenting the question. I've edited your question with capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: You should also replace that image with a larger one that is in focus.

Answer (score -3):

i think that after dividing the current of 8A, you can sum up the currents in the second contour
[image]

Comment: but im not really sure

Comment: You can accept your own answer.

Comment: You've posted this in the "Answer" section. Can you please use this [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/422487/edit) link to add this information into your "Question" instead?

Comment: @KevinKruse sorry first day still learning lol

Comment: Why does your KCL equation not include terms for current through the 8-ohm resistor or the 4 A source? Hint: Step 1 is to combine the 8 A and 4 A sources.